# How to proof this metric and $\mathbb{R}$ space together metric space?

Tags: real-analysis

$x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

$d\left( x,y\right) =\left| \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }\right|$

Second question: How to show this ball ? $B\left( 0,r\right)$

Comment: What have you tried when attempting to prove it is a metric on $\Bbb R$? It is very straightforward.

Comment: What do you mean "show this ball" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non negative

$d(x,y)\ge0$ because the definition of absolute value.

$d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$

$\left| \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }\right|=0\implies \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }=0\implies  \dfrac {1+\left| y\right|}{1+\left| x\right|}x=y$

So, both are positive or both negative. Further,

$\implies x+x\vert y\vert=y+y\vert x\vert\implies x-y=y\vert x\vert-x\vert y\vert=\vert y\vert\vert x\vert-\vert x\vert\vert y\vert=0\implies  x=y$

Symmetry

$d(x,y)=\left| \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }\right|=\left|-\left(\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }-\dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }\right)\right|=\left|\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }-\dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }\right|=d(y,x)$

Triangle inequality:

$$\left| \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {z} {1+\left| z\right| }\right|=\left| \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }+\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }-\dfrac {z} {1+\left| z\right| }\right|\le$$

$$\le\left| \dfrac {x} {1+\left| x\right| }-\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }\right|+\left|\dfrac {y} {1+\left| y\right| }-\dfrac {z} {1+\left| z\right| }\right|$$

[Because reasons](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~lakeland/Spring13/latexexample.pdf)

---

$B(0,r)=\{x\in\mathbb R|d(0,x)<r\}$

$\dfrac{\vert x\vert}{1+\vert x\vert}<r$ solving for $\vert x\vert$, $\vert x\vert<\dfrac{r}{1-r}$ with $r<1$. Thus, the ball is.

$$B(0,r)=\begin{cases}
   \mathbb R &\text{if}\; r\ge 1\\
   \left\{x\in\mathbb R\left| \dfrac{r}{r-1}<x<\dfrac{r}{1-r}\right.\right\}&\text{if}\;r<1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice work, but it's $d(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow \ x=y$.

Comment: Tanks. And yes, but the implication from right to left is still more trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. show that if $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an injective function, then $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ defines a metric over $\mathbb{R}$;
2. show that $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$ is an injective function (for example, show it is strictly increasing);
3. solve the inequality $\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}<r$, where $r>0$.